# Turning a list of tuple into a greyscale image knowing it's size

Tags: python, image, list

I possess a list of tuple extracted from tex it is the position of pixels on a greyscale image. How do I create y image using my list?

I have tried using array and pyplot without success

```
   [(5, 160), (5, 160), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, 387), (10, ...
```

This is the list of couple named Position it goes on and on gor about 3000 more couples

The size is 598 by 513

```
tab=np.full((A,B),255,dtype='uint8')

for i,j in Position:
    tab[i,j]=0

plt.imshow(tab,cmap='gray')

plt.show()

myarray = np.asarray(Position)

img = Image.fromarray(myarray)

img.save('test.png')
```

Comment: whats the value of pixels that are not in the list `position`?

Comment: the one in my list are black pixel the one not in the list are whites

Comment: Your code is doing fine. As long s your image is black and white, you can use 1 as white: `position = np.array(position);
img = np.ones([598,513]);
img[position[:,0], position[:,1]] = 0;
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray');
plt.show();`

Comment: thanks do you know if i can map it using PIL

Comment: use `fromarray()` : https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray